# WordPress privacy policy link disappears when adding wrapper

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to put the *privacy policy link* into an `<li>` element with **get_the_privacy_policy_link()**.
According to [WordPress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_privacy_policy_link/), the function has two optional parameters, that are `$before` and `$after`.

However when I echo the function, `echo get_the_privacy_policy_link(<li>", "</li>");`,
nothing appears. If I just simply call the function without the parameters, the link displays. (Of course, without the `<li>` tag.)

Is there a better way to solve this without checking whether the string is empty? I could just put the `<li>` before, but if there is no privacy policy, it would result in an empty list element.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the opening quotes on your `$before`:

```
<?php echo get_the_privacy_policy_link("<li>", "</li>");?>
```

Additionally the docs state:

> Returns the privacy policy link with formatting, when applicable.

I appears to require you have this page set in options and that the page is published.

Comment: In the original code I do have the quotes: `echo get_the_privacy_policy_link("<li>", "</li>");`

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike said ... You're missing a quote.

```
<?php echo get_the_privacy_policy_link( "<li>", "</li>" ); ?>
```